# Where should a displayable property be implemented?

Tags: design, class-design

I have a class that contains insurance benefits. There are many values, such as coverage level percentages, maximums, deductibles, etc. Most of the time, I only need a handful of display friendly properties, which are aggregates of all of the other properties. Other times, I need the values to perform more in-depth calculations.

Currently I use viewmodels to aggregate the properties into a display friendly values. However, each time I use the display friendly properties in a new app, I have to recreate the viewmodel. If I want to change how it's displayed, I have to revisit every app.

I considered either 1)creating a 'ForDisplay' property in the class which is, in effect, a built in view model of sorts. I've also considered a shared viewmodel where I pass the class(model) through a shared view model for transformation.

Is there a better way to make my class maintain it's detail AND it's display friendly values without visiting every app if I need to change something?

Comment: Maybe implementing helper classes for display conversion may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to give really detailed advice based on the information given, but I sometimes solve similar problems with simple inheritance;

In the contrived example below, I can pass around MyModel throughout code and use the 'detailed' parts. When I want to simplify properties for display, I create an instance of the child model from the parent. This is nice because I don't necessarily have to re-write the properties of the model class. Also, I can add reader only simplification to the child class without adding noise to the model that is used elsewhere.

A disadvantage is that it does expose all parent properties in the display model. If that doesn't fit your needs then this may not be a good choice for you.

Also, the method "from_my_model" uses a primitive copying technique. If your parent model is complex, and you want to copy all of its complexities, you will need to investigate better ways of copying the parent class.

```
class MyModel:
    def __init__(self, interest=3.124569):
        self._interest = interest

    @property
    def interest(self):
        return self._interest


class MyDisplayModel(MyModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @property
    def interest(self):
        return round(self._interest, 2)

    @staticmethod
    def from_my_model(parent):
        instance = MyDisplayModel()
        instance.__dict__ = parent.__dict__.copy()
        return instance


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parent = MyModel()
    print(parent.interest)

    display = MyDisplayModel.from_my_model(parent)
    print(display.interest)
```